# Formulario https://formcarry.com/ con javascript vanilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo un proyecto donde tengo que insertar un formulario con https://formcarry.com/

La propia web del formulario facilita un código en jquery para enviar una respuesta al usuario si se ha enviado correctamente el formulario. Estoy intentando pasar ese código jquery a javascript vanilla, para no tener que utilizar jquery en el proyecto, y estoy teniendo problemas.

El código a convertir es el siguiente:

```
$(function(){
  $(".ajaxForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("action");
    var enviado = $(".enviado")
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: href,
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(response){
        if(response.status == "success"){
          enviado.addClass("block");
        }else{
          alert("Error " + response.message);
          }
        }
      });
    });
});
```

El código que no me funciona es el siguiente:

```
var submitForm = document.querySelector('#submitForm')

function formcarry() {
  var ajaxForm = document.querySelector('.ajaxForm')

  ajaxForm.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = ajaxForm.getAttribute('action')

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(request.readyState === 4) {
        if(request.status === 200) {
          alert("ok")
        } else {
          alert("error")
        }
      }
    }
    request.open('Post', href)
  })
}

submitForm.addEventListener('click', formcarry)
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y también [mcve]. En tu pregunta dejas claro lo que deseas, pero no muestras lo que has avanzado ni tampoco en dónde tienes la dificultad. Mientras no se vea un esfuerzo de tu parte, es poco o nada lo que te podremos ayudar. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado.

El problema era que estaba trabajando desde local sin servidor. Para ejecutar AJAX es necesario un servidor local o subirlo a la red.